# Matplotlib: how to vertically align multiple legends

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have a plot which has three legends of different length and width. I'm trying to find a way to place them nicely onto the plot. Currently I'm placing them with the default `loc=` which is great for dealing with the vertical placement. The issue is that by default the legends are right aligned, which looks messy.

Is there a way to use the default `loc=` to place them on the plot, but to have them left aligned?

Example:
From the [legend guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#plotting-guide-legend).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

line1, = plt.plot([1,2,3], label="Line 1", linestyle='--')
line2, = plt.plot([3,2,1], label="Line 2\nThis is a \nvery long\nlegend", linewidth=4)
line3, = plt.plot([2,2,2], label="Can this be left justified?")

# Create a legend for the first two lines.
# 'loc' puts them in a nice place on the right.
first_legend = plt.legend(handles=[line1], loc=1)
second_legend = plt.legend(handles=[line2], loc=5)

# Add the legends manually to the current Axes.
ax = plt.gca().add_artist(first_legend)
ax = plt.gca().add_artist(second_legend)

# Create another legend for the last line.
plt.legend(handles=[line3], loc=4)

plt.show()
```

Which gives this

[image: three legend plot]

Now what I would really like is for the legends to left aligned but still on the right side of the plot. Like so:

[image]

I know I can place them at a specific location but to do this I need to specify both the x and y coords, which will be fiddly since all 3 have variable heights and widths.

Comment: Your suggestion is problematic as it would require matplotlib to shrink the main axes to allow that bottom legend to stay "on-image" and not be truncated as the right axis is typically very close to the edge of the display. So I think you'd have to manually place the legend and shrink the main axes to accomplish what you want.

Comment: daryl, I can control the width of the legend using a textwrap. So the horizontal extent is ok. The issue is placing them vertically. But I'm beginning to think that you are right, it looks like placing them manually is the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `bbox_to_anchor` to position legends precisely where you want them:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line1, = ax.plot([1,2,3], label="Line 1", linestyle='--')
line2, = ax.plot([3,2,1], label="Line 2\nThis is a \nvery long\nlegend", linewidth=4)
line3, = ax.plot([2,2,2], label="Can this be left justified?")

# Create a legend for the first two lines.
# 'loc' sets anchor position of the legend frame relative to itself, 
# bbox_to_anchor puts legend's anchor to (x, y) in axes coordinates.
first_legend = ax.legend(handles=[line1], loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.65, 1))
second_legend = ax.legend(handles=[line2], loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.65, 0.5))

# Add the legends manually to the current Axes.
ax.add_artist(first_legend)
ax.add_artist(second_legend)

# Create another legend for the last line.
ax.legend(handles=[line3], loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.65, 0))

plt.show()
```

The only number you would need is `x` position of the legends' `bbox_to_anchor` to align to (`0.65` in the example above).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Primer, this is really useful.

Comment: When I run this example with `fig.savefig("test.png")` , the bottom legend is truncated in the PNG file.

Comment: daryl, easily fixed by adding the tight layout argument `plt.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches = 'tight')`